# How fast does $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ ( $\alpha\leq1$) diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^\alpha}$ diverges if $\alpha\leq 1$.
How can I estimate the divergent rate when $\alpha$ is given.
For example, if $\alpha=1$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\alpha}=O(\log n)$; if $\alpha=0$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^\alpha}=O(n)$.

Comment: Hint: estimate this sum from below and from above by $\int_a^b x^{-\alpha}\mathrm dx$ where $a$ and $b$ have to be chosen in a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Abel summation technique from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225700/problem-with-abel-summation/225709#225709) to derive the asymptotic [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula#Asymptotic_expansion_of_sums) given by
$$\sum_{m=a}^b f(m) = \int_a^b f(x)dx + \dfrac{f(a) + f(b)}2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)'}(b)-f^{(2k-1)'}(a)\right)$$
In your case, $f(x) = \dfrac1{x^{\alpha}}$, $a=1$, $b=n$. Hence, we get that
$$\sum_{m=1}^n \dfrac1{m^{\alpha}} = \dfrac{n^{1-\alpha}-1}{1-\alpha} +\dfrac{1+n^{-\alpha}}2 + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}(-\alpha)\cdots(-\alpha-2k+2)\left(\dfrac1{n^{\alpha+2k-1}} - 1\right)$$