# Solving the recurrence $T(n) = T(n/2) + cn \cdot \lg \lg n - 1$

Tags: recurrence-relations

I'm trying to solve the recurrence

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
T(n) & = & T\left( \frac{n}{2} \right) + cn\lg \lg n - 1\\
T(2) & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
where $\lg n = \log_2 n$ to get the higher-order term exactly (in terms of $c$, presumably). I first tried to solve it iteratively, which got me the following expression that I have no clue how to evaluate:

$$
T(n) = c \sum_{i=1}^{(\lg n) - 1} \left[ \frac{n}{2^i} \lg((\lg n) - i) \right] - \lg n
$$

If I make the substitution $n = 2^m$ and $S(m) = T(2^m)$, then I get a slightly nicer recurrence
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
S(m) & = & S(m - 1) + 2^m c\lg m - 1\\
S(m) & = & \sum_{i=1}^m (2^i \lg i) - (m-1)
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Wolfram Alpha gives me a crazy-looking solution to the summation, but it's not really what I'm looking for (WA solution [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=S%28m%29+%3D+S%28m-1%29+%2B+c%2a%282%5Em%29%2a%28log_2+m%29+-+1)).

I'm pretty stuck at this point with this recurrence, after having also tried constructive induction on both $T(n)$ and $S(m)$ with no success, and at this point I've pretty much exhausted my toolbox. If anyone could offer any hints or general advice on solving this recurrence or similar reccurences, I would really appreciate the help. Thanks.

Comment: How do you have as argument n/2, when n can be odd? Is it the whole part of n/2 or?

Comment: @Belov I'm allowed to assume n is "nice" as needed, so in this case that it is a power of 2

Comment: Your T(1) doesn't make sense. lg (lg (1)) is not defined for any base.

Comment: @Zen: Oops sorry! Base case is supposed to be T(2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n = 2^m$. We then have
$$T(n) = T(n/2) + c n \log(\log(n))-1 \implies g(m) = g(m-1) + c \cdot 2^m \log(m \log(2))-1$$
where $g(m) = T(n)$. We hence get that (as you have already derived)
$$g(m) = c \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \left(2^k \log(k) + 2^k \log(2) \right)\right)-m + g(0)$$
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225700/problem-with-abel-summation), we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^m a(k)f(k) = A(m)f(m) - A(0)f(1) - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} A(k) (f(k+1)-f(k))$$
where $A(k) = \sum_{j=1}^k a(j)$. In our case, choose $a(k) =2^k$ (i.e., $A(k) = 2^{k+1}-1$) and $f(k)=\log(k)$. We then get that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^m 2^k \log(k) & = (2^{m+1}-1)\log(m) - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} \left(2^{k+1}-1\right)\log\left(1+\dfrac1k\right)\\
& = 2^{m+1} \log(m) - \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}2^k \log\left(\dfrac{k+1}k\right)}_{ = \mathcal{O}(2^m) \text{ since}\log\left(\frac{k+1}k\right)\leq \log(2)}
\end{align}
Hence, the leading term is
$$c \cdot 2^{m+1} \log(m)$$

Comment: Ah, summation by parts was the critical step I was missing! I thought the S(m) summation looked familiar when I wrote it down, but just couldn't put my finger on exactly why. Should have flipped through more of my notes. Thanks!